# MS Excel's alternative for ={A:A} formula in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

This must be a simple thing to do but somehow I am unable to find answer to this question. In google sheets, if you want to reference an entire column (e.g Column A) you will put ={A:A} and the entire column will be referenced. How do you achieve similar thing in MS excel?

EDIT: (Asked in comments to post specific example)
Lets assume google sheets contain the following data:
|  A |  B |  C |
|  1 | 5 | 9 |
|  2 | 6 | 0 |
|  3 | 7 | 9 |
|  4 | 8 | 0 |

Now if in cell D1 I type ={A:A}, the entire column A will be shown in column D.

|  A |  B |  C | D |
|  1 | 5 | 9 |={A:A}
|  2 | 6 | 0 |
|  3 | 7 | 9 |
|  4 | 8 | 0 |

becomes

|  A |  B |  C | D |
|  1 | 5 | 9 | 1 |
|  2 | 6 | 0 | 2 |
|  3 | 7 | 9 | 3 |
|  4 | 8 | 0 | 4 |

I dont have to drag the formula to the bottom or anything. It just shows the entire column
How do I do the exact same thing in excel?

Comment: That depends on which version of Excel you have.

Comment: Same. `A:A` is the address of the column `A`.

Comment: I am using office 365

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  For example:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"gold")
```

Excel does **not** support stuff like:

```
=COUNTIF(A12:A,"gold")
```

Comment: I want to retrieve the entire column by by having a formula only in the first cell. I want to get the exact values of the cells. Is it not possible in excel ?

Comment: @AhsanIqbal  If you update you original question with some specific GoogleSheets examples, we can offer Excel equivalents..........................................